# How to identify a name server that does not have DNSSEC implemented?

Tags: dns

I tried dig `+dnssec dig [domain name] +dnssec +short`. Is RRSIG the only attribute to confirm if a name server has DNSSEC implemented or not? How do I identify a name server that has no DNSSEC implemented?

Also, what tools can I use to test vulnerability to DNS cache poisoning?

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between *nameservers* with DNSSEC and *domains* (zones) with DNSSEC.

- If a domain uses DNSSEC, it will have RRSIG records for every name (as well as NSEC or NSEC3 records, usually), and at least one DNSKEY record at the zone root.
- If an authoritative nameserver supports DNSSEC, it will automatically give you RRSIG records *in addition to* the queried records as long as the `+dnssec` flag is set (e.g. querying for A will return A+RRSIG), and will return the appropriate NSEC/NSEC3 records when queried for nonexistent names.

It's very common to have nameservers with DNSSEC support serving zones that aren't DNSSEC-signed.

It's also technically possible (although won't work well) to have a nameserver that *doesn't* support DNSSEC attempt to serve a DNSSEC-signed zone; it would still answer direct queries for RRSIG records but wouldn't automatically include them when needed.